# How to dynamically add a component on link click in my Angular application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, components, angular11

I have three components: (1) a navigation bar, (2) home page with a left and right div, and (3)view-associates. On link from the navbar, I want to dynamically add the view-associates component into the home's right div. I have already implemented the following code (in the traditional JavaScript fashion) into the **navbar-component.ts** file:

```
addTemplateTag(){
    const link = document.querySelector('.nav-link');
    const showArea = document.getElementById('showArea');
    console.log(link);
    console.log(showArea);

    // check for specific class name to get appropriate template tag
    if (link.classList.contains('view-associates')){
      console.log('Found view-associates class in link. Getting tag...');
      // NOTE: the below two lines did work BUT still did not show component
      const templateTag = document.createElement('app-view-associates');
      showArea.appendChild(templateTag);
    }
  }
```

Here is the HTML code with the navbar and home components, respectively:

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav class="nav flex-column">
    <a class="nav-link view-associates" (click)="addTemplateTag()">View My Associates</a>
</nav>
```

**home.component.html (Before link click)**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="float-left left">
        <h1 class="title">Welcome</h1>
        <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
        <button class="btn btn-primary logout-btn" (click)="logOut()">Log Out</button>
    </div>
    <div id="showArea" class="float-left right">
    </div>
</div>
```

**home.component.html (After link click)**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="float-left left">
        <h1 class="title">Welcome</h1>
        <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
        <button class="btn btn-primary logout-btn" (click)="logOut()">Log Out</button>
    </div>
    <div id="showArea" class="float-left right">
        <app-view-associates></app-view-associates>
        <-- ^^^ appended but component not showing -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the images of the home page before and after the link click:

**Before (with browser console)**
[image: Before Link Click]

**After (with browser console)**
[image: After Link Click]

This above code did work but still did not show the view-associates component at all. How do I resolve this issue? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The given code inside addTemplateTag() function works perfectly in traditional JS way , but not in angular way. In angular, it must be divided in components and use ngIf to show/hide and replicate.

Comment: A clear understanding of basics in angular components will make all this a lot easier and clear.

Comment: I agree. I wanted to use an ngIf but I don’t know if I need to set any additional properties in the ts file or just use ngClass to just hide or show the components instead.

Comment: ngClass will only hide it visually, ngIf will remove it from DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngIf` and `ngSwitch` to show/ hide components dynamically. For example : -

in .html

```
<app-form></app-form>
<some-component *ngIf="isLoggedIn"></some-component>
<some-component *ngIf="!isWorking"></some-component>
<another-cool-component *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"></another-cool-component>
```

in .ts

```
export class MyFunnyComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn = false;
  cartValue: number;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Obviously there are some other ways to handle these scenarios but, for the start it might be enough. We might also have to pass `data` from child to parent and vise versa.